# MOSS 2007 Wiki Export to MS Word or PDF

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, ms-office, wiki, sharepoint-2007

I've started using MOSS 2007's wiki feature for storing the ongoing technical documentation related to a project I'm working on, and it occurred to me after I started writing a few pages that there's no easy way to export out all of the pages into one document.

For those of you familiar with MOSS 2007, any ideas how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

In the past I've created a site feature that exports SharePoint content to PDF and HTML but that was for publishing sites. I assume it needs some rewriting to make it working with the Wiki.

It basically iterates through the navigation of a site and all it's sub sites and reads all the pages stored in the "pages" document library. For each page it then extracts the content using XSLT.

Let me know whether I shall make the source somewhere available.

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: I think that would be very useful somewhere like CodePlex, if that's the right sort of place for it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create a view that shows the content for all of the wiki articles. It's not pretty; you'll get one really long web page. I don't have sharepoint up and running right now to tell you the exact steps, but I have done it before.

Comment: Please add the details when you get a chance. I'll upvote you for that.

Comment: When you're on the home page of the wiki, click on View All Pages at the bottom of the quick launch area. This takes you to the normal library-type view. On the toolbar click on Settings, then Create View. Select Standard View. Give the view a name. Uncheck all the columns except Name (linked...). Check Wiki Content at the bottom of the columns list. Select a sort order you like. Under Style, select Newsletter. You may want to add a filter to filter out the help page. Click OK and there you go. You may want to add some CSS to make the article titles bigger.

Answer (score 1):

[BlueRidge](http://wiki.bluebridge.de/) has an extension that allows you to export to PDF, but at 640+ euro it's a tad pricey.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy/paste your content into your desired document.  It's not convenient but it is a potential work around.

Answer (score 0):

I am also after a solution for this. We have a multilevel Wiki content that follows a levelling structures. Can we automatically export the MOSS Wiki content to a more structured database such as Excel, Access, or XML?